# Do "Forwards" Stack?

Tags: dungeon-world

So, I'm in love with Dungeon World, but I have a quick question about forwards.  Do they stack?  The +1 suggests that they do, but I just want to be sure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Stacking" is a concept that is not touched very much upon. Searching through the PDF, the only place it shows up is on page 327:

> *n Armor*: It protects you from harm and absorbs damage. When
>   you take damage, subtract your armor from the total. If you have
>   more than one item with *n Armor*, only the highest value counts.
>
> *+n Armor*: It protects you and **stacks** with other armor. Add its
>   value to your total armor.

Bold font added for emphasis. Here, it is mentioned that *+n Armor* stacks with your **highest** *n Armor* item/rule/whatever.

Now, why is this relevant to your question? On page 21, the rules explanation for *take +n forward* reads:

> ...Say “take +1 forward.” That means to take +1 to your next
>   move roll (not damage). The bonus can be greater than +1, or even
>   a penalty, like -1. There also might be a condition, such as “take +1
>   forward to hack and slash,” in which case the bonus applies only to
>   the next time you roll hack and slash, not any other move.

The issue of stacking is not mentioned here at all. The bonus is applied to your next (relevant) roll, *no matter what*.

In conclusion, yes. Bonuses stacks, unless otherwise stated in the rules. As an example of when two seperate bonuses *doesn't* stack, look on page 72, at the bottom of the page dedicated to the move *Aid or Interfere*:

> No matter how many people aid or interfere with a given roll, the
>   target only gets the +1 or -2 once. Even if a whole party of adventurers
>   aid in attacking an ogre, the one who makes the final attack only
>   gets +1.

Comment: I don't think this fits in the answer, so I'll put it here: Forget _everything_ you know about how stuff _usually_ work in rpg's, at least when reading through DW. Assume nothing! I suspect that your question stems from exposure to D&D, where it is important for different bonuses to have different "types" before stacking. You can have only one of each "stat" in DW, but every frickin' bonus adds. Unless otherwise stated, of course :)

Comment: Yep. You won't always be *able* to enjoy every available bonus on a single roll, because getting the fiction to line up that way is not always easy. **+1 forward when defending your Love**, **+1 forward while avenging a wrong against your nation**, and **+1 forward when being gentle**? Good luck (or *awesome* roleplay!) getting those to all apply to a single move! :D

Comment: Yes, this stacking mentality does come from D&D.  The fiction is a great way to think about the game!  This is the kind of mentality DW seems to try and encourage as well.